# How to show next record on refresh Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, increment

A very basic question but I can't seem to get my controller code right.

On page refresh I want the next row in the database to be shown.

At the moment I have 5 rows with each with a string value in `:author`

In my controller I have:

```
@pages = Pages.find(1)
```

In my view I have :

```
<%= @pages.author %>
```

This will obviously display the author string of my first record in the table Pages. How can I then show the second record in the table if the page is refreshed?

I believe it will be something to do with `.increment` or `+=` operator similar to javascript but I can't seem to work it out.

Apologies for the rookie question and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a page refresh, or can it come from a user clicking a link or performing some action?  Incrementing on page refresh kind of goes against the stateless intent of REST design.

Comment: Hey tyler, clicking a button would be even better, if you have any advice on how to achieve this that would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need a page refresh and would prefer clicking a link, you should go that route.  You can start at whatever you have now, e.g. `http://mypage.com/` and set a counter in the controller:

```
@counter = params[:counter] || 1
@pages = Pages.find(@counter)
```

And then in your view somewhere, create a link like:

```
<a href="http://mypage.com/?counter=<%= @counter + 1 %>">Link to next page</a>
```

This link will point to `http://mypage.com/?counter=2` on the first page load, and then it will point to `http://mypage.com/?counter=3` after the user clicks the link the first time, and so on.